# Vaadin 7 : TableFieldFactory

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Is there a way to implent TableFactory interface with specific fields related to propertyId ? 
I only get one type of field since i'm using a generic class for all my tables, and the i'm missing CheckBox boolean value (groovy code):

```
class DefaultTableFieldFactory implements TableFieldFactory {
    @Override
    public Field<?> createField(Container container, Object itemId, Object propertyId, Component component) {
        TextField t = new TextField()

        switch(propertyId) {
            case "firstname": t.setNullRepresentation("");
            case "lastname": t.setNullRepresentation("");
            case "mobile": t.setNullRepresentation("");
            case "tel": t.setNullRepresentation("");
            case "email": t.setNullRepresentation("");
            default: break;
        }
        t.setWidth("95px")

        return t
    }
}
```

So i need to use this class above which implments DefaultTableFieldfactory in order to have the null representation as "" (instead of "null" ) in  my whole application.

The goal is to provide for my custom components (more than 30) this null representation in a single place, I want to use this class as my default factory for every table, and connect it like i've done before:

```
def contacts = (Grails.get(FundService)).getAllContacts(fundId)
        def cContainer = new BeanItemContainer<Contact>(Contact.class,contacts)


        def t = new Table()
        t.containerDataSource = cContainer
        t.setTableFieldFactory(new DefaultTableFieldFactory())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin provides a DefaultTableFieldFactory which does map

- Date to a DateField
- Boolean to a CheckBox
- other to TextField

The DefaultTableFieldFactory is already set on the table. So in your case, if you just want to have CheckBoxes for your boolean fields, I wouldn't implement an own TableFieldFactory. Here's an example:

```
Table table = new Table();

table.addContainerProperty("text", String.class, "");
table.addContainerProperty("boolean", Boolean.class, false);
table.setEditable(true);

Object itemId = table.addItem();
table.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("text").setValue("has accepted");
table.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("boolean").setValue(true);
```

If you really need to have your own TableFieldFactory then Vaadin recommends:

> You could just implement the TableFieldFactory interface, but we
>   recommend that you extend the DefaultFieldFactory according to your
>   needs. In the default implementation, the mappings are defined in the
>   createFieldByPropertyType() method (you might want to look at the
>   source code) both for tables and forms.

In your code given in the question you always return a TextField. For your missing CheckBoxes you need to return in the specific case a CheckBox.

Don't forget to `setEditable(true)` when using FieldFactories.

More information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html) under 5.16.3. Editing the Values in a Table.

Comment: Thanks, but i already know what is DefaultTableFactory since i'm implementing it in my code. The goal here is to provide this factory to handle different types of Fields in a single factory, an to apply this pattern to the table's container datasource (see code modified above)

Comment: @ludo_rj Then have a look at the createFieldByType() method in the DefaultFieldFactory class provided by Vaadin which returns a CheckBox when appropriate.

Comment: yep that's the one i was looking for :) Because DefaultFieldFactory.createFieldByPropertyType is static it cannot be overridden so it requires extracode to be implemented correctly in TableFieldFactory..

Comment: @ludo_rj well I already mentioned that in my answer, if you have a close look at it.