# Vaadin table bound to SQLContainer, how to show field type as link

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I use `Vaadin's` Table and set data using `SQLContainer`:

```
resultTable.setContainerDataSource(mySQLContainer);
resultTable.setColumnHeader("internalid", "Internal Id");
```

Now, I want to make this field as a Link in table column. 
Since I am setting all the fields directly via `SQLCOntainer`, I am not sure how to change appearance for a single field from that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello Experts, can anyone help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TableFieldFactory to provide your own type mapping.

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TableFieldFactory.html

Just specify your own class on the table and it should be OK.

Look also here: [Vaadin 7 : TableFieldFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713035/vaadin-7-tablefieldfactory)

A example with inline class:

```
    // Set a custom field factory that overrides the default factory
    table.setTableFieldFactory(new DefaultFieldFactory() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8585461394836108250L;

        @Override
        public Field createField(Container container, Object itemId,
                Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
            // Create fields by their class
            Class<?> cls = container.getType(propertyId);

            // Create a DateField with year resolution for dates
            if (cls.equals(Date.class)) {
                DateField df = new DateField();
                df.setResolution(DateField.RESOLUTION_YEAR);
                return df;
            }

            // Create a CheckBox for Boolean fields
            if (cls.equals(Boolean.class))
                return new CheckBox();

            // Otherwise use the default field factory 
            return super.createField(container, itemId, propertyId,
                                     uiContext);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Andre, could you give some example? The point is that 9 fields come from database and only 1 out of them has to be link. I prefer to stick .setContainer() instead of coding to add all the fields. Could you share some code example if TableFieldFactory can be used in this case?

Comment: I added a example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way for showing column values as links like this is by registering a [ColumnGenerator](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.ColumnGenerator.html) for that column by calling [Table.addGeneratedColumn](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#addGeneratedColumn%28java.lang.Object,%20com.vaadin.ui.Table.ColumnGenerator%29) 
The generator can itself access the backing container properties and return instances of `com.vaadin.ui.Link`. For the column ID, you can use the existing container id to "shadow" the container column.

Comment: Hi, In this case I need to add it manually everytime. Its as good as not using .setContainer() but add all fields by myself. Is this understanding correct?